# Attach a font icon in a "<li>" floating on the right

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to attach an icon on the right side of the list using only css class member.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwgqVp?editors=110

So when I attach a class named 'location' to a desired list It should display an icon on the right like so:

[image: Edited image to demonstrate the desired result]

I tried using float:right; but it just stacks my list with the next one..

```
ul.listb li.location{
    content: '\f124'; /* FontAwesome char code inside the '' */
    font-family: FontAwesome; /* FontAwesome or whatever */
    /*this Wont work it just stacks with the next list*/
    /*
    float: right;
    */
}
```

What makes this hard for me is that I don't want to add anything on the html side. I only want to use 'location' class to make my icon show up in the list.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using both `:before` and `after` :pseudo-elements, you will have to use `border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray` instead of `background: lightgray` and use `content: '\f124'` along with it because `content` only works with `:after` or `:before` :pseudo-elements.

**[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPQrbK)**

```css
ul.listb {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
ul.listb li {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE10+ */
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
ul.listb li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul.listb li.location:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '\f124';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 50px;
}
ul.listb li.online::before {
  margin-left: 4px;
  content: '\f0c8   ';
  /* FontAwesome char code inside the '' */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  /* FontAwesome or whatever */
  color: green;
}
ul.listb li.offline::before {
  margin-left: 4px;
  content: '\f0c8   ';
  /* FontAwesome char code inside the '' */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  /* FontAwesome or whatever */
  color: lightgray;
}
ul.listb li:hover {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  /*color: #428BCA;*/
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
  <ul class="listb">
    <li class="online location">John Doe</li>
    <li class="online">Doe John</li>
    <li class="offline">Bill Gates</li>
    <li class="online">Steve Jobs</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow a lightning fast answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @l0oky - You're Welcome. :) It's still not fast enough. :p

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using float for the icon of navigation, you can just make it at the background :

```
background: url("http://www.icone-png.com/png/39/39015.png") no-repeat;
background-size: 20px 20px ; // Any size you want for your image
background-position: right 2px; // you can change the position if you want
```

You can try it yourself : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mywBYJ

Best Regards

Comment: WOW - too many good answers.. I wish I can accept more then one answer :D